# How to print return values from a boolean?

Tags: java, boolean, return-value

I am trying to print the value return value from a boolean, to check that the if statements are working correctly. I get no errors but nothing shows in the console. Any advice is appreciated.

Also if it makes a difference the code is not part of the main class. If it does, is there a way of printing the return value of the boolean from the main?

Here is what I have tried.

```
public boolean inCollision(double x, double y, furniture f) {
    if (x + radius <= f.getXpos(0) || x + radius > f.getXpos(2)) {
        System.out.println("False");
        return false;
    }
    if (y + radius < f.getYpos(0) || y + radius > f.getYpos(2)) {
        System.out.println("False");
        return false;
    }
    System.out.println("True");
    return true;
}
```

This is where furniture comes from

```js
public class furniture {
 
 private String name;
 private double xpos;
 private double ypos;
 private double width;
 private double height;
 
 
  public furniture (String n, double x, double y, double w, double h)
  {
  name = n;
  xpos = x;
  ypos = y;
  width = w;
  height = h;
 
  } 
  
  public double getXpos(int c){
   if (c==0 || c==1){return xpos;}
   else {return xpos+width;}
   
  }
  
  public double getYpos(int c){
   if (c == 0 || c == 1){return ypos;}
   else {return ypos+width;}
   
  }
  
 
 

  public String toString() {
    return "the "+ name+ " has a height of "+height+" and a width of "+width+". Its coordinates are ("+xpos+","+ypos+")," ;
    
    
  }

  }
```

Below is the whole page of code for the first part.

```js
public class roomba {
 
 private double xpos;
 private double ypos;
 private double radius;
  
 public roomba(double x, double y, double r){
  
  xpos = x;
  ypos = y;
  radius = r;
 }
 
 
 public String toString() {
    return "the coordinates of the roomba are ("+xpos+","+ypos+").It has a radius of "+radius ;
    
    
  }
 
 
 public boolean inCollision(double x, double y, furniture f){
  if (x+radius <=f.getXpos(0) || x+radius >f.getXpos(2)){
   System.out.println("False");
   return false;
  }
  if (y+radius < f.getYpos(0) || y+radius > f.getYpos(2))
  {
   System.out.println("False");
   return false;}
  
  System.out.println("True");
  return true;
 
  


 }
```

Comment: JAVA is not the same as JavaScript.

Comment: When calling this method, it will always print something to the standard output stream. If "nothing shows in the console" you are either redirecting this stream or not calling the method.

Comment: What @Seelenvirtuose said.

Comment: From where this "furniture" variable popped out in Java ?

Comment: I have the edited in the whole code. I would appreciate it if you could tell me how am I redirecting the stream or not calling the method.

Comment: I've looked through the code several times.  I cannot see where you are calling `inCollision`.  Perhaps you should point it out to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main class you have to create two objects : roomba and furniture

```
roomba r = new roomba(1f,1f,1f);
furniture furn = new furniture("chair",2f,2f,2f,2f);

boolean retValBool = r.inCollision(1.5f,1.5f,furn); //
System.out.println(" inCollision method returns : " + retValBool);
```

In java you can handle for printing all primitive data types the same way. That means you can print integers, doubles , booleans etc with the same way :)

Comment: Sorry for the wait I was looking for a way to print the boolean, but I still have no results. Where are my supposed to put the code you gave me? I tried putting in it the roomba class but I get an error telling me to delete the three dots within the inCollision. I also tried in the main class but it says that the method inCollision is undefined.

Comment: Thank you very much, it feels so good when something finally works. I appreciate the time you have taken to understand my problem and the patience you have had to give me a solution I can understand :D